# При обновлении страницы подгружается старая версия пакета

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc, npm, package

Подскажите, пожалуйста, такая проблема, есть пакет pl-component-pack [image: package.json] Вроде все работает хорошо, но иногда при обновлении страницы или при переходе на нее по ссылке в 1 из 10 случаев загружается старый пакет версии 1.5.0 Вот что в `source`: [image: source], а вот как выглядит путь к файлу: [image: физический и виртуальный] (да, далее должно быть pl-component-pack.min.js), хорошо, мы смотрим на этот файл физически на машине [image: вот он]

Видно что обращение идёт к нему, и там всё как нужно с новой версией. Очень странная ситуация, плавающий баг, повторяется в 1 из 10 случаев, как я уже говорил. Удаление package-lock.json и полная переустановка - результатов не дала. Дайте пожалуйста совет - куда копать. Поиск по проекту тоже не дал результатов, видимо, он как-то загружает этот пакет с npm ???

Вот что в pacage-lock.json  [image: pacage-lock.json]
А вот ссылка на npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/@factoringplus/pl-components-pack

Comment: Кеш браузера?..

Comment: чистил, ребилдил несколько раз, пробовал в разных браузерах, и даже на разных компах..